# How to call a cell’s function when a scrollViewDidEndDecelerating occurs from UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

```
  cell.callingApi(featurePost: featurePost)
  cell.mainImageView.imageChangeByMotion()

  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  }
```

How to call a function Defined inside UICollectionViewCell from it’s CollectionView for a particular cell when a scrollViewDidEndDecelerating occurs Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Khalid Afridi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6640196/khalid-afridi)'s answer and here is the code that would help you do that:

```
for i in 0 ..< yourCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            if let cell = yourCollectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? YourCustomCollectionViewCell {
                cell.yourFunction()
            }
        }
```

Note: If you know the `IndexPath` value of the cell you are trying to access there is no need to loop all the cells. Also don't forget to replace `section` value with the section that contains your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find your cell first. Easiest will be using indexPath to get the exact cell you want. Once you have a reference to that cell then you can call any function from that cell.